# Pass data between UpdateView and CreateView in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, web-services, dynamically-generated, create-view

I had two models Permit & Course.

```
class Permit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skill_course = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, related_name="+", blank=True)

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, related_name="courses",blank=True,)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="courses",blank=True,)
```

Clicking a permit object displays students who acquired permit dynamically(in UpdateView with GET method).

How to create course with those students?(in CreateView with POST method)

Do I have to pass data between 2 views? I want to create a utils.py file, there create a method with data I will reuse in other methods or class, but the class or function will have `request` and `pk`, I don't know how to return a dict, because it should be have request and template right? I was trapped in this, really appreciate for any help, thanks in advance......

Comment: Can you explain why you use `+` as `related_name`? This is not a valid Python identifier, so that means it can cause a lot of problems when you want to obtain the permits of a course.

Comment: Typically you do not pass data directly, it is enconded in the `POST` request: for example a `POST` with the permit name/identifier.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem using '+' for related name is valid and is used to not create a backwards relation; please check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Answer (score 0):

First you should active [session middleware](http://django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware) in `setting.py`.

Then use something like this:

```
   def update_project_filter(request):
    ...
    selected_project_id = project_form.cleaned_data["Project_Name"].id
    request.session['selected_project_id'] = selected_project_id
    ...

def update_project(request):
    ...
    selected_project_id = request.session.get('selected_project_id')
    ...def update_project_filter(request):
    ...
    selected_project_id = project_form.cleaned_data["Project_Name"].id
    request.session['selected_project_id'] = selected_project_id
    ...

def update_project(request):
    ...
    selected_project_id = request.session.get('selected_project_id')
    ...
```